# Maximizing (and derivating) log-likelihood of penalized logistic regression

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, derivative, regularization

I'm trying to solve Exercise 18.3 of "Elements of Statistical learning" by Hastie et al. and I'd be really grateful for any hints.

> Show that the fitted coefficients for the regularized multiclass logistic Regression Problem $$\max_{\{\beta_{0k},\beta_{k}\}_{1}^{K}}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}logPr(g_{i}| x_i)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}\|\beta_{k}\|_{2}^{2}\right]$$ satisfy $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\hat{\beta}_{kj}=0, j = 1,...,p.$$

$p$ is the number of Features, $K$ is the number of classes.

EDIT: I actually think that $\max\limits_{\{\beta_{0k},\beta_{k}\}_{1}^{K}}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}logPr(g_{i}| x_i)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}\|\beta_{k}\|_{2}^{2}\right]$ is a Lagrange optimization Problem, so derivating with respect to $x$ and $\lambda$ and then Setting to Zero should do what I Need.
But turns out that I'm even getting confused by derivating! 
$$Pr(g_{i}| x_i) = \dfrac{exp(\beta_{g_i0}+x_i^T\beta_{g_i})}{\sum\limits_{l=1}^Kexp(\beta_{l0}+x_i^T\beta_l)}$$ and I'm not quite sure if I should compute $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$ with $i=1,...,N$ or $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}$$ with $i=1,...,N,j=1,...,p$, $f$ being the function inside the square brackets. Well I tried both and I guess it went wrong both times as I couldn't achieve what I'm trying to proove. 
I didn't forget $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}.$

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got yourself a bit lost here.

Hint #1 - assume you have a set of betas which does not sum to zero, but instead you have $\sum_{k=1}^K\beta_{kj}=c $.

Hint #2 - what happens to the first term $\log [Pr(g_i|x_i)] $ if you add the same constant to each intercept term $\beta_{0k }=\beta_{0k}+d $ ?

Comment: Regarding Hint #2: Nothing happens to the first term, $Pr(G=k|X=x)=\dfrac{exp(\beta_{k0} + x^T\beta_k)}{\sum\limits_{l=1}^Kexp(\beta_{l0} + x^T\beta_l)}$ in this case, so the additional d cuts itself out.

Comment: How can you use this in combination with hint #1?

Comment: Do you want me to regard $\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\beta_{kj}$ as a constant $d$ that's added to $\beta_{0k}$?

Comment: Does the second term vary if you add a constant $e$ to each term. Is there an optimal choice of what to add?

Comment: Adding it like this: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\|\beta_k+e\|_2^2$ ? Then it does vary and I get an upper boundary which would be smallest for $e = 0$...

Comment: How do you get $e=0$ as the best choice? This is least squares 101... best choice for $e $, take derivative and set to zero. Solve for $e$...

Comment: Expanding $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}\|\beta_{k}+e\|_{2}^{2}$ gets me to $|\beta_{11}+e|^2+...+|\beta_{1p}+e|^2+..+|\beta_{K1}+e|^2+..+|\beta_{Kp}+e|^2$ which could be summed up again to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}|\beta_{k1}+e|^2+...+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}|\beta_{kp}+e|^2$. Derivating this:   $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}2*|\beta_{k1}+e|+...+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}2*|\beta_{kp}+e|$. Then $-\frac{1}{pK}(\sum\beta_{k1}+...+\sum\beta_{kp})=e$. Now, if $e$ would be zero, this mean $\sum\beta_{kj}=0$ for all $j$. Is that my proof already?

Comment: Typo in the derivative, I wanted to write bracket instead of the absolute values in the sums. I'm wondering if it would be possible that $(\sum\beta_{k1}+...+\sum\beta_{kp})=0$ but the single components $\sum\beta_{kj} \neq 0$?